# Location of origin in the Sympy geometric module?

Tags: python, geometry, sympy

Maybe a candid question.
In the Sympy geometric module, where is located the (default) origin?
In the upper left "corner" (with the y-axis that grows towards the "bottom") or in the lower left "corner" (with the y-axis that grows towards the "top")?

In advance thank you for your lights,

Yannick

PS: sorry for the purists/experts if my terminology and/or my formulations are incorrect or if my question is stupid.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs for [`sympy.geometry.point.Point.origin`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/geometry/points.html?highlight=origin#sympy.geometry.point.Point.origin)

> A point of all zeros of the same ambient dimension as the current point

So that means in 2D it would be at `(0,0)`, in 3D it would be `(0,0,0)`, etc. Therefore by typical convention (e.g. right-hand rule) this would be the lower-left corner.

Comment: It seems you have right if figures shown in http://blancosilva.github.io/post/2014/10/28/Computational-Geometry-in-Python.html - found just now - are relevant.